# How can i call/execute function of functional component outside react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios

I have a custom component called `Loader`:

```
export const ModalLoader = props=>{
  const {
    loading,
    ...attributes
  } = props;

  const [isModalOpened, setModal] = useState(props)
  const closeModal = ()=>{
    setModal({loading:false})
  }

  return(
    <Modal
      transparent={true}
      animationType={'none'}
      visible={isModalOpened.loading}
    >
      //my Loader view
    </Modal>
  )
}
```

i want to execute `closeModal()` function in `axios` instance, because of my `axios` is not a `react component`, i got an `error` when i tried this code:

```
AxiosHttp.interceptors.response.use((res)=>{
  //tried to call closeModal()
  ModalLoader.closeModal()
  CustomLog(res.data, 'Interceptor')
  return res.data;
},(err)=>{
  CustomLog(err, 'Interceptor Error')
  if(err.message == 'Network Error'){
  return Promise.reject(err)
})

export default AxiosHttp
```

error detail:

[image]

is there a way to call `closeModal()` from `axios` instance?

Comment: I would suggest using an event system instead. Ie dispatch an event in your axios callback that your ModalLoader is listening for. That way you dont have to worry about accessing component functions outside the component. It also helps keep the different parts of your code separate (one wont depend on the other)

Comment: You cannot access a component's method like this. If you're defining the interceptor inside your component (seriously doubt that) you could pass a reference of this function from your component's body. But you probably wan't to set a global state(using redux for instance) and dispatch an action to change the modal's state

Comment: I'm using react navigation as navigate, and this lib has an _ability_ to pass a function of navigation props outside react component like [NavigationService](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html), so i can use `NavigationService.goBack()`, my case similar like this one. But i dont know how to deal with ref like react navigation did.

Comment: You should use useEffect hook for setting the modal i.e setModal. Wrap your setModal inside useEffect hook

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using context. Then you can use in any other component